# Blob distorting audio on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, blob, speech-recognition, android-chrome

I am trying to input audio stream from microphone and save it to blob so I could send it to Speech Recognition API endpoint. This works perfectly on google chrome on desktop, but I noticed errors when I would switch to a mobile device browser (android google chrome). After outputting the audio to a file, I found out that on desktop, the file sounds fine, but on my phone, it would be completely distorted. After more research, it appears that android chrome [does not support Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob);

Is there some work around for this issue?

This is how I add the audio to the Blob and save it to a file:

```
                var blob = new Blob([audio], { type: 'audio/wav' });
                var reader = new FileReader;
                reader.onload = function() {
                    window.open(this.result.replace(/data:.+?\/[^;]+/, "data:application/octet-stream"));
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

**Update**: I am trying to save the audio to a file but reader.readAsDataURL() and any other of the reader methods(according to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)) is expecting a blob object. My audio object is a type of ArrayBuffer. My other question is: how can I output ArrayBuffer to a file?

**Another Update**: According to [this link](https://caniuse.com/#search=blob%20urls), blob should be supported by android chrome. Nevertheless, my audio is distorted, maybe the issue could be somewhere else?

**Update**: After more research, I found out that our audio array might not be properly encoded. To process the audio from the microphone, we are using ScriptProcessor, but according to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode), it is deprecated, and not supported on android chrome. For reference to how we are encoding the audio input, you can check out [this library](https://github.com/davrous/BingSpeech). I am thinking that the issue might be solved by switching to using the [Audio Worklet](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#audioworklet).This is how I am using the Script Processor Node(as you can also see in the referenced library):

```
       // Create ScriptProcessorNode
        this.scriptProcessorNode = this.options.context.createScriptProcessor(this.options.bufferLen, numChannels, numChannels);
        // Connect scriptProcessorNode (Theretically, not required)
        this.scriptProcessorNode.connect(this.options.context.destination);
        // Create callback to update/analyze floatFrequencyData
        var self = this;
        this.scriptProcessorNode.onaudioprocess = function (event) {
            self.analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(self.floatFrequencyData);
            self.update();
            self.store(event);
            self.monitor();
        };
        // Connect scriptProcessorNode
        this.options.source.connect(this.scriptProcessorNode);
```